# Format Date for different Locals using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, java.util.date

I saw this question is asked several places but the given answers are not clear to me. That's why im asking it again.

Is it possible to get the Locale specific date by just passing the Locale argument with same date pattern ? for example how can i do something like this

```
String pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
Date d1 = new Date();
 SimpleDateFormat f1 =  new SimpleDateFormat( pattern , Locale.UK );
 f1.format(d1);
 // formatted date should be in  "dd/MM/yyyy" format

 SimpleDateFormat f2 =  new SimpleDateFormat( pattern , Locale.US );
 f2.format(d1);
 // formatted date should be in "MM/dd/yyyy" format
```

Above code doesnt give me the expected result. Is there a way to do something like this ?

I have tried using DateFormat factory method. The issue with that is i cannot pass the format pattern. it has some predefined date formats (SHORT,MEDIUM etc)

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
@Test
public void formatDate() {
    Date today = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat fourDigitsYearOnlyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
    FieldPosition yearPosition = new FieldPosition(DateFormat.YEAR_FIELD);

    DateFormat dateInstanceUK = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, 
            Locale.UK);
    StringBuffer sbUK = new StringBuffer();

    dateInstanceUK.format(today, sbUK, yearPosition);

    sbUK.replace(yearPosition.getBeginIndex(), yearPosition.getEndIndex(), 
            fourDigitsYearOnlyFormat.format(today));
    System.out.println(sbUK.toString());

    DateFormat dateInstanceUS = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,
            Locale.US);
    StringBuffer sbUS = new StringBuffer();
    dateInstanceUS.format(today, sbUS, yearPosition);
    sbUS.replace(yearPosition.getBeginIndex(), yearPosition.getEndIndex(), 
            fourDigitsYearOnlyFormat.format(today));
    System.out.println(sbUS.toString());
}
```

It basically formats the date using the style [DateFormat#SHORT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#SHORT) and catches the location of the year using a [FieldPosition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/FieldPosition.html) object. After that you replace the year with its four digits formart.

Output is:

```
13/11/2013
11/13/2013
```

**EDIT**

Use with any pattern

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
DateFormat dateInstance = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(dateInstance.format(today));
dateInstance.format(today, sb, yearPosition);
sb.replace(yearPosition.getBeginIndex(), yearPosition.getEndIndex(), 
        fourDigitsYearOnlyFormat.format(today));
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Output is:

```
13-11-13
2013-11-13
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But there will be a issue if the date pattern is not equal to "dd/MM/yyyy". isn't it ?

Comment: @Dilantha, with this method you don't have to pass any pattern, it is given through the `locale` and the `style` parameters, you just replaye the 2 digts year the four digits one. In order to do so, a FieldPosition is used with the parameter `YEAR_FIELD` to locate the year part no matter how the format is.

Comment: @Dilantha, I've edited my answer for use with any other pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance(int style, Locale locale)
```

The java doc for SimpleDataFormat states this :

> Constructs a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29) using the given pattern and the default
>   date format symbols for the given locale. Note: This **constructor may
>   not support all locales**. For full coverage, use the factory methods in
>   the DateFormat class.

Comment: cannot use DateFormat since the there are only 4 predefined styles available (SHORT,MEDIUM etc) .I need to define my own style..